# Isotropy group acts via isometries, isotropic representation

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras, topological-groups

Let $H$ be a lie group, $\Phi : H \times M \to M$ be a differentiable group action on a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, and $H_p:=\{ h \in H | \Phi(h,p)=\Phi_h(p)=p \} $ be it's stabilizer/isotropy group. The claim now is that for $h \in H_p$

$$ d(\Phi_h)_p : T_pM \to T_{\Phi_h(p)=p}M $$ is an isometry, i.e.

$$ g_p(v,w)=: \langle v,w \rangle_p = \langle d(\Phi_h)_p v, d(\Phi_h)_p w \rangle_p.$$

Since we have $\Phi_{h_1}\circ \Phi_{h_2}=\Phi_{h_1h_2}$, we have $d(\Phi_{h_1})_p \circ d(\Phi_{h_2})_p=d(\Phi_{h_1h_2})_p$ and $d(\Phi_e)_p=id_{T_pM}$ and thus the isotropy representation goes to

$$ H_p \to GL(T_pM,g_p), h \mapsto d(\Phi_h)_p $$ But why does the image actually lie in $O(T_pM,g_p)$?

I'm sure the answer is rather trivial, but I don't see it currently.

Comment: Surely your source is assuming the action is by isometries? A smooth action need not be by isometries, e.g. $GL(n)$ acting on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(V, \langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle)$ be an inner product space. A vector space isomorphism $L : V \to V$ is *orthogonal* if $\langle L(v_1), L(v_2)\rangle = \langle v_1, v_2\rangle$. The collection of all orthogonal isomorphisms of $(V, \langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle)$ is denoted by $O(V, \langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle)$.

With this in mind, the equation $\langle v, w\rangle_p = \langle d(\Phi_h)_pv, d(\Phi_h)_pw\rangle_p$ shows that $d(\Phi_h)_p \in O(T_pM, \langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle_p) = O(T_pM, g_p)$.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer. Maybe my question was not worded appropriately, but the content of your answer was clear to me and the actual question was why $\langle v,w \rangle_p = \langle d(\Phi_h)_p v, d(\Phi_h)_p w \rangle_p$ holds, hence the "claim" I put before. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this claim?

Comment: I suppose reading the claim of a theorem would have cleared it up. The theorem states: "Let $(M^n,g)$ be a complete $H$-homogenous space, $p \in M$. If $H$ operates effectively on $M^n$ and if $\Phi(H) \subset Isom(M^n,g)$ is a closed subgroup of $Isom(M^n,g)$, then $H_p$ is compact." So that $M$ is $H$-homogenous i.e. that $\Phi$ acts isometrically and trasitively is the answer to my non-question?

Comment: Yeah, you're assuming $H$ acts by isometries so the claim in question holds by definition.